# Burying and growling

Tags: dogs, aggression, vocalizations, digging

My dog just did something she had never done before. I gave her a treat, but instead of eating it she went outside and started to bury it near our tree.

About two months ago she had puppies and even when they're just walking nearby her treat she starts to growl at them.

Is this normal?
Will she hurt her babies?
Why has she started doing this?

Comment: she wants to save her treat for later (maybe the babies) and therefor keeps it save there. this is normal, just leave her to it.

Comment: Growling at the puppies is a normal way to educate them to behave correctly, I wouldn't be concerned as long as it is just a short growl that ends as soon as the puppies show the wanted behavior (like backing away or showing other signs of surrender)